# Looking for a video media player program that saves colour/volume profiles for individual videos?

Tags: media-player

I use VLC right now but I'm tired of having 24 VLC players open because I watch that many different things each week so I just leave them open indefinitely; having to set each one up with the different colour/brightness/volume when the computer crashes is time-consuming.  Also, having those many players open gets crazy.

Is a good video media player available that lets you create or save profiles for videos watched or going to watched such as colour/brightness/volume?

Windows 7 64-bit.  Freeware or paid?

Comment: What version of VLC are you using?

Comment: Version 1.1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Check This out;
In VLC you can pass your settings as an arugment in a script. Probablly your best tool as what your doing is quite specific.

I'd disable HW accelaraton as this will impact the overlay setting that maybe managed by your video driver. `--overlay="disable"`

From Chapter 4. Advanced use of VLC  [Guide](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html#id589318)

```
**Note**
Windows users have to use the --option-name="value" syntax instead of the --option-name value syntax.

Image properties filter

**Module name : adjust**

--contrast <float> Image contrast in the 0-2 range.

--brightness <float> Image brightness in the 0-2 range.

--hue <integer> Image hue in the 0-360 range

--saturation <float> Image saturation in the 0-3 range.

--gamma <float> Image gamma in the 0-10 range.
```

Comment: Oh boy. Is there anything simpler? Too technical for me.

Answer (score 0):

VLC will still work fine... 
Firstly, I don't fully understand your question, however to save the settings (even if the computer crashes) can be done by going to **Tools**> **Preferences**> (on the bottom left corner) **show settings** set to **all** > **+Video**> **+filteres**> **Image adjust** > (change the settigns you want) > **Save**.

Your prefrences will now be saved, even if you close VLC or your computer crashes.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I want to save the settings for each individual video so I don't have to set the colour/brightness/volume each time I watch a weekly show.

Comment: Is the content streaming?

Comment: Nope. Just videos on my drive.